# Windows Azure Active Directory Authentication - Visual Studio 2012 tools

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory

I've been struggling with this one now for a good week or so. I need to connect via Azure (not ACS, the Active Authentication Provider) up to Office 365. Literally the only way I've seen to do this seamlessly is using a tool named "Windows Azure Active Directory Authentication Tools for Visual Studio 2012" - as seen in http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/02/18/microsoft-asp-net-tools-for-windows-azure-active-directory-visual-studio-2012-4/.

However, the link to this download is ... http://dl01.blob.core.windows.net/waad/AspNetToolsForWAAD_VS2012.msi and, hey, guess what... file does not exist!

Has anyone out there done this before and can give me guidance, or better yet, has a version of this VS2012 tool?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be the download URL you're looking for - http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e21bf653-dfe1-4d81-b3d3-795cb104066e

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't, I have that tool and it's a completely seperate one - see this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eB0rMBkNiGo

Comment: Try it again. i think the file is back now.  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=282306

Comment: Wohoo, its back online, just as I need it! :) I'll accept your answer, just as your deserved of the points :P